# How Can I keep adding a certain value to a certain point?

Tags: c

over 13 pounds the cost to ship is an additional $1.55.  For example, if the weight of the package is 56.6 pounds then the cost to ship based on weight would be $587.10In addition to the cost to ship based on weight, the program calculates the cost to ship based on distance.  It cost $3.21 for every 321 miles or part thereof.  For example, if the distance is 251 miles, then the cost based on distance is $3.21.

I was wondering how, for example, it was 20 pounds how would i keep adding 1.55 and stop it?
Same with the distance if it is 700 i would need to add 3.21 twice but how would I stop it?

Comment: A little more detail is needed. Does it add 1.55 for each pound past 13? Or does it just add a flat 1.55 if it's heavier than 13?

Comment: 1.55 if its heavier than 13 also, every 321 miles that's added it adds 3.21 so for example 700 miles 3.21 would be added twice

Comment: What do you mean... "stop it"? The computer does what you tell it to do. Add $1.55; it won't add infinity instead. If you're struggling with a piece of code, you should show that code (in [mcve] form).

Comment: Sounds like the world's most expensive shipping. At any rate, this is simple math. "how do I keep adding..." you just multiply. Try doing your homework yourself, you wont learn anything if other people do it for you.

Comment: @Havenard I dont copy anything, I did mines more differently I was just wondering how I would do the calculation part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the properties of integer division to get the quotient needed to multiply each value by.

```c
int total_cost = 0;

int weight = 0;
int distance = 0;

int overweight_weight = 13;
float overweight_cost = 1.55;

int mile_threshold = 321;
float price_per_mile = 3.21;

//get weight, distance here

if(weight > oveweight_weight) {
  int ajdusted_weight = weight - overweight_weight;
  price += overweight_cost * adjusted_weight;
}

//integer division means a whole number is returned - how many times the 
//distance goes into the threshold. we add 1 to round up for the "...or 
//part thereof" requirement.
int quotient = (distance / mile_threshold) + 1;

price += price_per_mile * quotient;
```

This will multiply the price by the miles traveled, rounding up for any parts of miles left over. (Note that if you travel exactly 321 miles, this will treat it as though you had gone *over* 321.)

Comment: im confused mostly the weight part would this still follow the rule? Of for each pound over 13 pounds the cost to ship is an additional $1.55.  For example if the weight of the package is 56.6 pounds then the cost to ship based on weight would be $587.10

Comment: Ah - I misunderstood that based on your earlier comment on the question. Answer updated.

Comment: @Cloudss How does 56.6lb cost $587.10 to ship exactly? That's $10.37 per pound!

Comment: @NickReed I was wondering how you calculated the 1.55 part? I see what you did but can you explain to me how u got it?

Comment: @Cloudss `1.55` is the amount you specified in your original question, and your comments! *"[...] the cost to ship is an additional $1.55."*